# Alter registration and comment forms

Tags: plugin, form

I am deveoping a small plugin that needs to alter the registration and comment forms to add 4 hidden fields that have data inside that I gather from the configuration panel, and when the form is submitted, a js onlick event must be called to send those 4 hidden field data (it's a tracking software similar to google analytics).

So far I've built the xml manifest and xml field structure following [this link](http://library.logicsistemi.it/en/joomla/general-topics/40-joomla-25-extending-users-data-with-custom-fields) and [this link](http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_the_article_component) tutorials.

The first issue is that the fields are hidden, so the data is not entered by the user. I need to fill those fields data with:

```
<?php echo $params->get('my_param'); ?>
```

but on those tutorials I don't see any example on how to fill the fields when the form is loaded. I'm also lost on how to attach a js onclick event to the submit form. It is enough to implement onAfterRender()?

EDIT: The registration form is the one where an user register to the joomla cms.
[image: Joomla registration form] 
The comment form is any comment form added by a third party extension below posts and pages.

Comment: which registration and comment forms?

Comment: cppl I hope to have answered your question.

Comment: would it be an option to use a ready built (free) component such as ChromoForms or RSForms? You can easily modify these with js events such as onload, onsumbit and ondisplay etc

Comment: Unfortunately not. I need to develop a package that I distribute, I cannot rely on a third-party solution.

Answer (score 4):

I think you will need `onContentPrepareForm()` for that, then you can load your fields in it. [Here](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin) is a good tutorial how to make it.

To attach a js onclick event to the submit form, you will need to [override](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core) form [template](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/components/com_users/views/registration/tmpl/default.php) and put your JS code inside.

Comment: the tutorial was perfect to help me add the fields. The issue is that I cannot change the template or I need to do it programmatically (with a plugin). There is any other way to add js to the form submit?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know another method.