# Add onclick/onsubmit event to form submit

Tags: plugin, javascript, jform, form

I have made a plugin that add few fields on joomla registration form.
Now I need to add a javascript event on submit that will handle those extra fields I added, but I couldn't find any way to manipulate the submit button of the form.
How could I add an onclick or onsubmit event to the submit button of the registration form?

Comment: See my answer to almost the same question [here](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/3786/alter-registration-and-comment-forms/3819#3819).

Comment: I saw your answer, but it requires to change the template. Since I'm doing a plugin, I need to be able to do it without changing templates.

Answer (score 2):

This is a list of the available Joomla events:

http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events

As I don't know what exactly you're trying to do you might just want to browse the list and see if anything sounds suitable to you. You could then just use the event handler in your plug in. If you need any explanation as to how to use these events just let me know

Edit:just noticed that you were asking for a js event to handle your fields. You can do it in php with the joomla events too. The handler will give you access to the fields - returning false should abort the operation. Is this what you need?